# Using Indirect within Advanced Filter

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am currently creating an automated report that imports two or more CSV files from a given folder. The unique identifier that I need to use for a VLOOKUP is in an obscure column, so what I needed to do was Cut and Insert the found column onto Column 'A'. Example Below.

```
With wksRawData
    '~~> Move Process ID Column to Column 'A' for VLOOKUP
    .Columns(WorksheetFunction.Match("pid", .Range("1:1"), 0)).Cut
    .Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToLeft

    '~~> Remove Additional Headers
    .Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
End With
```

This part works great, but I have a formula in another worksheet that is supposed to reference `$A2` and it gets changed to `$B2`. The reason why it should reference `$A2` is because it is being used in an Advanced Filter Formula, and is the very first data point. Formula Below.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($C:$C, 'Raw Data'!$A2)=0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

When used in tandem with the other Advanced Filter columns this formula will whitelist any manually added unique identifiers. Example Below.

```
PID Whitelist  |      |  user  |  proc          |  PID Whitelisted?
---------------+------+--------+----------------+------------------
          182  |      |  root  |                |  < FORMULA_ABOVE >
           11  |      |  test  |                |  < FORMULA_ABOVE >
         1776  |      |        |  Jazzy Rabbit  |  < FORMULA_ABOVE >
```

I've attempted to use `INDIRECT`, `ADDRESS`, and `INDEX` in the place of `'Raw Data'!$A2`, but since they reference an absolute destination the Advanced Filter always uses the very first unique identifier value; instead of the current row's value.

Thank you in advance for your time, and I really appreciate any assistance provided!

- NOX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest simply rewriting the formula immediately after the VBA column insert. Example (with improved (?) formula:

```
With wksRawData
    '~~> Move Process ID Column to Column 'A' for VLOOKUP
    .Columns(WorksheetFunction.Match("pid", .Range("1:1"), 0)).Cut
    .Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToLeft

    '~~> Remove Additional Headers
    .Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
End With
sheets("Some_Sheet").cells(x, y).formula = "=NOT(COUNTIF($C:$C, 'raw data'!$A2))"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'aslo one additional variant of the @Jeeped idea, without formulas

With wksRawData
    .Columns(Range("1:1").Find("pid").Column).Cut
    .Columns(1).Insert
    .Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
End With
Sheets("Some_Sheet").Cells(x, y).Value = _
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns(3), Sheets("raw data").Cells(2, 1).Value)
```